# how to fetch data using assignment or function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, fetch, crud

I have a component where I fetch data:

here is my code :-

```
class HomePage extends Component{

constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
      eminem: []
  }
}

url = "https://deezerdevs-deezer.p.rapidapi.com/search?q=";

componentDidMount = () => {

        fetch(this.url + "eminem", {
            "method": "GET",
            "headers": {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "x-rapidapi-host": "deezerdevs-deezer.p.rapidapi.com",
                "x-rapidapi-key": [key]
        }
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseObject) => {
            console.log(responseObject);
            this.setState({ eminem : responseObject})
        }

        )

        .catch((err) => {
            this.setState({ error: true });
            console.log('An error occucred:', err);
        })   

}



 render(){
   return(
       <>
          <div className="col-12 col-md-9 offset-md-3 mainPage">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-9 col-lg-11 mainLinks d-none d-md-flex">
                    <a href="#">TRENDING</a>
                    <a href="#">PODCAST</a>
                    <a href="#">MOODS AND GENRES</a>
                    <a href="#">NEW RELEASES</a>
                    <a href="#">DISCOVER</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-10">
                    <div id="rock">
                        <h2>Eminem</h2>
                       <div className='row'>
                           { this.state.eminem.data.forEach(item => {
                                <div className='col-3'>{item.title}</div>
                           })}

                       </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                </div>

       </>
   )
 }


 }
```

But I've got an error: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions. I can't understand what I've missed. And give me advice what do I have to understand in react to avoid such mistakes. Cause I'm a newcomer in react world and wanna understand all the concepts.

Comment: Have you checked the answer?

Answer (score 0):

**First :** As your initial state looks like this :

```
this.state = {
    eminem: []
}
```

If you are getting your data inside `responseObject.data` then change this

```
this.setState({ eminem : responseObject})
```

To :

```
this.setState({ eminem : responseObject.data })
```

---

**Second :**

Because you are not returning anything from loop, first you need to change `forEach` to `map` and then you need to return JSX from it.

Change this :

```
{ 
    this.state.eminem.data.forEach(item => {
        <div className='col-3'>{item.title}</div>
    })
}
```

To :

```
{ 
    this.state.eminem.map(item => { // <--- map
        return <div className='col-3'>{item.title}</div> // <--- Return
    })
}
```

OR (shorter version)

```
{ 
    this.state.eminem.map(item => <div className='col-3'>{item.title}</div>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hi can just replace your componentDidMount handler with below one and try if it's solving your problem or not because what I think that you use inappropriate formate for defining that method

```
componentDidMount  () {

    fetch(this.url + "eminem", {
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "x-rapidapi-host": "deezerdevs-deezer.p.rapidapi.com",
            "x-rapidapi-key": [key]
    }
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseObject) => {
        console.log(responseObject);
        this.setState({ eminem : responseObject})
    }

    )

    .catch((err) => {
        this.setState({ error: true });
        console.log('An error occucred:', err);
    })   

}
```

and also return the element from the loop like this

```
{ this.state.eminem.data.map(item => <div className='col-3'>{item.title}</div>)}
```